# What could be stopping OnDisconnectedAsync from being called for clients who disconnect disgracefully?

Tags: c#, disconnect, asp.net-core-signalr

When a client disconnects disgracefully (such as cable pull, crash, or internet drops). OnDisconnectedAsync on the server is never called. I've waited upwards of 15 minutes with a breakpoint inside the function.

I am using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR (1.0.2)`.

My application is being hosted as an `Azure App Service`.

This is my disconnect function:

```
   public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_accountContextIDMap.TryGetValue(Context.ConnectionId, out int accountID))
            {
                ClientRequest_UserLoggedOut(accountID);
            }

            Logger.Write($"{Context.ConnectionId} Disconnected");
            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Write($"{ex.Message}\n{ex.StackTrace}");
        }
    }
```

If I sit a breakpoint at the top of this function it's never called. It is called fine when I close or exit my application in a normal manner.

According to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events it states.

> If a client application or the computer that it's running on crashes
>   or goes to sleep (for example, when the user closes the laptop), the
>   server is not informed about what happened. As far as the server
>   knows, the loss of the client might be due to connectivity
>   interruption and the client might be trying to reconnect. Therefore,
>   in these scenarios the server waits to give the client a chance to
>   reconnect, and OnDisconnected does not execute until the disconnect
>   timeout period expires (about 30 seconds by default).

The statement about `OnDisconnected` being called after 30 seconds by default does not seem to be ringing true for me. Any help on figuring out where I may have gone wrong in setup would be appreciated.

**In my Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     ...
     services.AddSignalR();
     ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseSignalR(route => { route.MapHub<GameHub>("/gameHub", GameHubConfigureOptions); });
    ...
}

private void GameHubConfigureOptions(HttpConnectionDispatcherOptions options)
{
    options.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
}
```

Comment: Are you using IIS?

Comment: No. I'm using an Azure App Service.

Comment: OK that *does* use IIS.

Comment: I made the incorrect assumption that you meant IIS as apart of a virtual/physical server,  where I have access to the standard IIS interface and controls.

Comment: The documentation you're referring to is the old SignalR - which is completely different. It probably still holds true though, but I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET Core 2.1, SignalR servers don't monitor their clients to see if they are still active. Clients **do** monitor Servers but not the other way around. We added this support in ASP.NET Core 2.2 though (preview 3 [just released](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/10/17/asp-net-core-2-2-0-preview3-now-available/)). In 2.2 the client pings the server and if the server hasn't heard from the client in a while, it should mark the client as disconnected and fire this event.

Comment: I'm on .NET Core 3 and it still doesn't get hit